# Set total input equal quantity * price value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to when user chose a product and enter the quantity  the total input = quantity * price using jquery

HTML

```
    <div id='sample'>

<div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" name="select_product[]">
      <option data-price=200 value=1>tes1</option>
      <option data-price=218 value=2>tes2</option>
      <option data-price=80 value=3>tes3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="qty[]" value="" placeholder="Quantity">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control price" name="price[]" value="" placeholder="Price">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control " name="total[]" value="" placeholder="total">
  </div>
</div>
<button class='generate'>
  Generate New Form
</button>

</div><!-- .sample -->
```

Jquery

```
    var sample = $('#sample').html();
function set_price( slc ) {
    var price = slc.find(':selected').attr('data-price');
    slc.parent().parent().next().next().find('.price').val(price)
}

$('#sample').on('click','.generate',function(){
    $('#sample').append(sample);
})

$('#sample').on('change','select.selectpicker',function(){
    set_price( $(this) );
})
```

check it live here from here -> https://jsfiddle.net/qxn0L6jv/12/

Comment: Your html structure is not good enough .. wrap all forms inside `<div id="forAllForms">` and wrap each form inside  another `<div id="forForm">` .. and put your generate button outside  `<div id="forAllForms">` .. with this structure you can easily control your js code

Comment: Sorry `<div class="forForm">` because Id must be unique

Comment: Syam please check the answer and let us know problem solved or not

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
    <script> // dodal area 
$(document).on('mouseout','.price',function(){
  var quantity  = $(this).parent().parent().prev().find('input[type="text"]').val();
  var price     = $(this).val();
  if(quantity !=='' && price !==''){
    $(this).parent().parent().next().find('input[type="text"]').val(parseInt(quantity) * parseInt(price));
  }
});

$(document).on('mouseout','input[placeholder="Quantity"]',function(){
  var price     = $(this).parent().parent().next().find('input[type="text"]').val();
  var quantity  = $(this).val();
  if(quantity !=='' && price !==''){
    $(this).parent().parent().next().next().find('input[type="text"]').val(parseInt(quantity) * parseInt(price));
  }
});

</script>
```